# How do I find the equations of motions for a relativistic particle?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, variational-calculus

I have it working for the Lagrangian of a classical particle in a gravitational potential:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
EulerEquations[1/2 m (X'[t])^2 - m g X[t], {X[t]}, t]
```

It outputs:

```
{-m (g + (X'')[t]) == 0}
```

---

However, I am not sure how to get it to work for a relativistic particle. What I have so far is:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
EulerEquations[m Sqrt[((c X0'[t])^2 - (X1'[t])^2 - (X2'[t])^2 - (X3'[t])^2)], {X1[t]}, t]
DSolve[%, X1[t], t]
```

It outputs:

$$
\left\{\frac{m \left(c^2 \text{X0}'(t)^2 \text{X1}''(t)-c^2 \text{X0}'(t) \text{X0}''(t) \text{X1}'(t)-\text{X1}''(t) \text{X2}'(t)^2+\text{X1}'(t) \text{X2}'(t) \text{X2}''(t)+\text{X3}'(t) \left(\text{X1}'(t) \text{X3}''(t)-\text{X1}''(t) \text{X3}'(t)\right)\right)}{\left(c^2 \text{X0}'(t)^2-\text{X1}'(t)^2-\text{X2}'(t)^2-\text{X3}'(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}=0\right\}
$$

and

$$
\left\{\left\{\text{X1}(t)\to \int _1^tc_1 \sqrt{c^2 \text{X0}'(K[1])^2-\text{X2}'(K[1])^2-\text{X3}'(K[1])^2}dK[1]+c_2\right\}\right\}
$$

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are asking.

The equation of motion is indeed correct for an arbitrary parametrization of the world line $x^\mu(s)$. Indeed, one needs to vary the action with respect to all four coordinates $x^0(s)$, $x^1(s)$, $x^2(s)$ and $x^3(s)$.

One can easily see this by varying the action ($\eta_{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(-, +, +, +)$)

$$
S = m \int \mathrm{d}s \sqrt{-\dot{x}(s) \cdot \dot{x}(s)}
$$

where $\dot{x}(s)$ denotes the derivative with respect to $s$ and $x \cdot y \equiv x_\mu y^\mu$.

Indeed, the equations of motion are

$$
\ddot{x}^\mu
=
\frac{\dot{x} \cdot \ddot{x}}{\sqrt{- \dot{x} \cdot \dot{x}}}
\dot{x}^\mu
$$

However in the *proper time parametrization* one has $\dot{x} \cdot \dot{x} = -c^2$ and the right-hand side vanishes.

I do not see an easy way how to handle this reparametrization in Mathematica.

A very hacky solution (for two coordinates and $m = c = 1$) is

```
Clear[lagrangian]
Derivative[1, 0][lagrangian][x0_'[t_], x1_'[t_]]:= x0'[t]/lagrangian[x0'[t], x1'[t]]
Derivative[0, 1][lagrangian][x0_'[t_], x1_'[t_]]:=-(x1'[t]/lagrangian[x0'[t], x1'[t]])
vars = {x0, x1};
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
eqs = EulerEquations[lagrangian@@(#'[s]&/@vars), #[s]&/@vars, s];
el1 = Eliminate[
  Flatten[eqs~Join~{#''[s]==D[lagrangian[x0'[s], x1'[s]], s]#'[\[Tau]]+lagrangian[x0'[s], x1'[s]]^2 #''[\[Tau]]}&/@vars],
  {x0''[s], x1''[s]}
];
el2 = Eliminate[
  Flatten[{el1}~Join~{x0'[s]^2-x1'[s]^2==lagrangian[(x0^\[Prime])[s], (x1^\[Prime])[s]]^2}],
  {x0[s], x1[s]}
];
Select[Last@el2, FreeQ[#, lagrangian]&]
(* x0''[\[Tau]] == 0 && x1''[\[Tau]] == 0 *)
```